# How can I add more code to this?

Tags: php, customization, query, content, excerpt

```
    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query( "cat=11&posts_per_page=1" );
   if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
       while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
           $my_query->the_post();
           the_excerpt();
       }
   }
   wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Where it says the_excerpt, how come I am unable to add other code alongside this? I'm guessing it's because it's still within the PHP tag, but I am unsure of how to seperate the two. Is there a way to make a section where the_excerpt is so that I may add additional code? I'm trying to add:

```
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div class="postdetails">
Written by <strong><?php the_author(); ?></strong>
<?php the_time ('j F, Y'); ?>
Posted in: <strong><?php the_category(', '); ?></strong>
<?php the_tags(); ?>
</div>
```

and THEN the excerpt

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert new code you need to break php code and past your new html+/-php code. But pay attention that after passing all will have correct syntax.

Your question should be made like this:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( "cat=11&posts_per_page=1" );
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
        $my_query->the_post(); ?>

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="postdetails">
            Written by <strong><?php the_author(); ?></strong>
            <?php the_time ('j F, Y'); ?>
            Posted in: <strong><?php the_category(', '); ?></strong>
            <?php the_tags(); ?>
        </div>

        <?php the_excerpt();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```